# Por que no me aparece la imagen cuando la consulto?

Tags: javafx

Por que no me aparece la imagen cuando la consulto?

Este es mi código:

```
@FXML
private void consultarEstudiante(MouseEvent event){
    llenarCbNormales(cbConEstTip,cbConEstEPS,cbConEstCin);
    try {

        con=new Conexion();
        con.abrirBD();
        Estudiante E = new Estudiante();
        ResultSet r = E.ConsultarEstu(con.getConnection(), cbxConsultaEstudiante.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() );
        if(r.next())
        {
            ConIdEst.setText(String.valueOf(r.getLong(1)));
            cbConEstTip.setValue(r.getString(2));
            conNom.setText(r.getString(3));
            conApe.setText(r.getString(4));
            conCel.setText(String.valueOf(r.getLong(5)));
            conEstFecha.setValue((r.getDate(6)).toLocalDate());
            cbConEstEPS.setValue(r.getString(7));
            conTel.setText(String.valueOf(r.getInt(8)));
            cbConEstCin.setValue(r.getString(9));
            conNomAcu.setText(r.getString(10));
            conCelAcu.setText(String.valueOf(r.getLong(11))); 
           byte byteImage[] = null;
            // obtener la columna imagen, luego el arreglo de bytes 
            Blob blob = r.getBlob("FOTO");
            byteImage = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());

            // crear el Image y mostrarlo en el ImageView
            Image img = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage));
            System.out.println("bdeyyfb");
            FotoEst.setImage(img);






        }

    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MenuController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    con.desconectar();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba seteando la variable byteImage de la siguiente forma:

```
byte[] byteImage = null;
```

Comment: Hola Carlos. Lee [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tu respuesta añadiendo explicaciones. Un saludo